# Compare two array and delete value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array.
1st array is `$newarray = ('489289', '536516', '332833', '536516')`

2nd array is

```
$rockin = array(
'489289' => array('536516','value1'),
'332833' => array('536516'),
);
```

I want to delete some value of $newarray.
Suppose we are looping from $newarray

1. Initially 489289 is assigned value.
2. I want to check whether the value associated to 489289 from $rockin array (i.e. value1 or 536516) also exist in $newarray.
3. If there is exist 'value1' or '536516' in $newarray then, delete 489289 from array!

So in above case 489289 would be deleted (from $newarray)
AS 536516 is associated value of 489289 in $rockin array AND 536516 also exist in $newarray

Till now I have tried this code

```
foreach ($newarray as $group_id) {
    foreach ($rockin as $myfrcikingcl) {
        foreach ($myfrickingcl as $myfrickingleader) {
            if($group_id==$myfrickingleader)
            {
                 unset($newarray[$group_id]);
            }
        }              
    }              
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your language.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understood you want to do:

```
$newarray = array('489289', '536516', '332833', '536516');

$rockin = array(
                '489289' => array('536516','332833'),
                '332833' => array('536516'),
          );

foreach ($rockin as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $newarray)) {
            $key = array_search($array, $rockin);
            $newarray = array_diff($newarray, array($key));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using $group_id as a key, but it's a value. You have to unset by key, like this:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($newarray); $i++) {
    foreach ($rockin as $myfrcikingcl) {
        foreach ($myfrickingcl as $myfrickingleader) {
            if ($newarray[$i] == $myfrickingleader) {
                 unset($newarray[$i]);
            }
        }              
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($newarray as $k => $v) {
    if(is_array($rockin[$v])){
        foreach ($rockin[$v] as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($value, $newarray)){
                unset($newarray[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```